# Specify charset for importscripts in webworkers

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I am using webworkers for executing a script seperately apart from my main js thread. While importing the script inside the webworker how to specify the charset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no defined way to do it.**

According to specs, [*fetch a classic worker imported script*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#fetch-a-classic-worker-imported-script) **must** read the fetched data as UTF-8:

> 5. Let source *text* be the result of [UTF-8 decoding](https://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/#utf-8-decode) response's [body](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-response-body).

(Same applies for [fetch a classic worker script](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#fetch-a-classic-worker-script) b.t.w.)

This leaves no room for doubt. Even setting the charset in the Content-Type header wouldn't help here (while it should for [*fetching classic scripts*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#fetch-a-classic-script)).

Now, it seems Chrome doesn't honor this rule (at least not for data:// URLs, I didn't try with real file served, and for blob:// URLs they don't even look at the defined charset...), but Firefox does.

```js
// we store the text encoded as base64 to preserve the encoding
// original text is `postMessage("é and ü")`
const script_url = "data:text/javascript;charset=windows-1252;base64,cG9zdE1lc3NhZ2UoIukgYW5kIPwiKQ==";

// importScript() test
{
  const worker_script = `importScripts( "${ script_url }" );`;
  const import_worker = new Worker( URL.createObjectURL( new Blob( [ worker_script ], { type: "text/javascript" } ) ) );
  import_worker.onmessage = (evt) => {
    console.log( 'importScripts:', evt.data );
  };
}

// Worker script test
{
  const direct_worker = new Worker( script_url );
  direct_worker.onmessage = (evt) => {
    console.log( 'worker script:', evt.data );
  };
}

// inline script test
{
  const script = document.createElement( 'script' );
  script.src = script_url;
  document.head.append( script );
  onmessage = (evt) => {
    console.log( 'inline-script:', evt.data );
  };
}
```

---

Of course, there are ways around that:

- Definitely the best solution is to **re-encode your scripts as UTF-8.**
- Another completely hacky solution is to fetch your script as a Blob, read it as a DOMString using the correct encoding, and then generate a new UTF-8 Blob that you'd serve to `importScripts`. [Doable](https://jsfiddle.net/g1upcax0/), but really ugly.